# Execution of function on first time open only

Tags: python

Context:- *I will convert my code to exe that's why the code won't be readable.* I am trying to prevent copying of my paid software. in which I am using machine GUID as a Licence

Question: How to run a function only on a first-time startup? Here I have written the part of the code -

```
    result = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "MachineGuid")
    ID = str(result)
    
    licence_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\System\\read.txt'
    
    def first_time_open_only():           #
        file = open(licence_path, 'w')    #
        file.write(ID[2:38])              #These codes should only run only on first-time startup
        file.close()                      #of the software
                                          #
    first_time_open_only()                #
    
    with open(licence_path) as f:
        contents = f.read()
        if contents == str:
            pass
        else:
            root.destroy()
            
    root.mainloop()
```

I have tried increasing the value of a number each time the function is executed, but It wasn't working and could not find the answer anywhere in the internet.

Comment: you probably want to store the fact that you opened it in some file, and just keep checkin that file on every run

Comment: It looks like you try to implement some sort of licensing mechanism. Which makes this more or less XY problem. Apart from that, converting to exe will hardly stop motivated user to decompile the exe.

Comment: exactly, but the only problem is that - when I open it again, it changes back to the original value and does the same thing again.

Comment: @buran Is there anyway to restrict it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context:- I will convert my code to exe that's why the code won't be readable. I am trying to prevent copying of my paid software. in which I am using machine GUID as a Licence.

```
result = _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "MachineGuid")
ID = str(result)

licence_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\System\\read.txt'

def first_time_open_only():           #
    file = open(licence_path, 'w')    #
    file.write(ID[2:38])              #These codes should only run only on first-time startup
    file.close()                      #of the software
                                      #
first_time_open_only()                #

with open(licence_path) as f:
    contents = f.read()
    if contents == str:
        pass
    else:
        root.destroy()
        
root.mainloop()
```